# getDeviceList returns devices that are no longer connected

Tags: android, usb

I have a Galaxy Nexus (running Android 4.2.2) connected to my computer via USB.  The device is connected in device mode with USB debugging enabled. There are no devices connected to the handset.

When I run the debugger, one device shows up as connected, but I do not have any devices connected.  The device that's showing up is not connected to the computer.

When the phone is rebooted, `getDeviceList()` reports no connected devices, which is correct.

Is this a known bug? Is there a way to **refresh the device list** to ensure it's only reporting devices that are actually connected?

Comment: Please tell us your Android version.

Comment: Updated to include Android version (4.2.2). I don't recall this particular bug surfacing before when this device was running ICS.

Comment: same issue here, did you find any answer brian?

Comment: Not for this case, unfortunately.  I didn't see it come up again during the development though.

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue on two of my development devices, running 4.1.2, building against API level 12. It definitely seems to be related to removing the device while some application has it open.

I'm using multiple USB devices through a hub, but only one device seems to get left in the list when this issue happens. As well, when I re-connect the hub, I usually have to re-connect the devices, but the ghost entries will vanish, replaced by new proper ones. I have noticed that I never get an intent broadcast for the ghost entry, though, so that's good.

Comment: @nitz What are the makes of the devices? Have you seen this issue with Android 4.4?

Comment: @BrianV I'm still on 4.1.2, so I'm not sure if it happens in 4.4 or not yet. (Though I think we're due for new devices here in a couple of months, so perhaps that's gonna change!) Right now we're using Galaxy Note 1s (The 4 softbutton model, I think it's the one before they introduced the 2soft/1hard button model.) I have an original Xoom running something similar and can't say I particularly noticed it happening on that one, so it might be something in the samsung driver causing it!